# Can not see JSON posting from iPhone to my MVC Rest Service

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

None of the articles are working for me.  It's seems like something so simple but I haven't had any luck.

I've been testing using cURL, Fiddler, and Firefox Poster.

The json object i'm posting is: 
'{"addressCity":"Miami","addressLine1":"123 Main","addressLine2":"#445","addressState":"fl",addressZip":"33029","companyName":"MyCoInc","email":"me@me.com","firstName":"Pepe","lastName":"Perez","phone1":"305-3333333",phone2":"","phone3":"","phoneFax":""}'

My Model Class is:
    public class BusinessJoin
    {
        public string addressCity { get; set; }
        public string addressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string addressLine2 { get; set; }
        public string addressState { get; set; }
        public string addressZip { get; set; }
        public string companyName { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string phone1 { get; set; }
        public string phone2 { get; set; }
        public string phone3 { get; set; }
        public string phoneFax { get; set; }

```
}
```

My Controller looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult postJoinForm(BusinessJoin myJSON, string APIKEY)
    {
        var request = HttpContext.Request;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //all good
        }
        else 
        { 
            //no good
        }
```

}

And in my Global.asax.cs file I included the following in Application Start:

```
        ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new JsonValueProviderFactory());
```

What is going on??

Thanx in advance..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand try check in header

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset: <your_charset>
```